# 2 solutions for inhomogeneous ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the simple ODE: $X\,\dot{T}+Y\,T = C$

I like calculating homogenous and inhomogeneous solutions separately:

$\texttt{Homogenous:}\quad$  $X\,\dot{T}+Y\,T = 0 \quad\Rightarrow\quad T(t) = C_1\,e^{\textstyle -\frac{Y}{X}\,t}$

$\texttt{Inhomogeneous:}\quad$ Ansatz: $T(t) =a_0+a_1t \quad\Rightarrow\quad X\,a_1+ Y\,(a_0+a_1\,t) = C \quad\Rightarrow\quad a_1 = 0,\quad a_0 = \dfrac{C}{Y}$

Adding both together I'd be cocksure to claim $T(t) = \dfrac{C}{Y}+C_1\,e^{\textstyle -\frac{Y}{X}\,t}$  is the solution.

But checking with a program it says $T(t) = \dfrac{C-C_1\,e^{\textstyle -\frac{Y}{X}\,t}}{Y}$

How is that coming? I only get the same solution using substitution but either way has to lead to the same thing.

Comment: They're the same function. $C_1$ is an arbitrary constant, so $-C_1 /Y$ is also an arbitrary constant. This linear equation is also separable

Comment: but depending on the Amplitude $C_1$ or $-C_1/Y$ I'd get 2 different function for the same starting conditions?

Comment: No, because the arbitrary constant will "adjust" to the initial conditions and give you the same answer. Convince yourself with, for example, $T(0)=1$ and $C\neq 1$.